# Cannot connect to camera service when using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to tell the system I want to take a picture:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, null);
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri
                    .fromFile(new File(filePath)));
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_ACTIVITY);
```

It works like a champ, the first time.  Subsequent tries yield the following exception:

> E/CameraHolder( 8300):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to
>   connect to camera service
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native
>   Method) E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:110)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:90)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:100)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   com.android.camera.Camera.ensureCameraDevice(Camera.java:1626)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1686)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   com.android.camera.Camera.access$5800(Camera.java:94)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   com.android.camera.Camera$5.run(Camera.java:949)
>   E/CameraHolder( 8300):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

I imagine I have to somehow release the camera object, but since I'm not directly acquiring it, I have no idea how to do this.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything of the sort, I use exactly that code all the time.  Can you provide more code surrounding how this code is actually called and what you do with the result?  Also, is this repeatable on more than one device?  Cheers.

Comment: Also, which version of Android are we talking about here? And does this happen on the emulator?

Comment: Android 2.2, 2.1. And no, the emulator doesn't have a camera.

Comment: The emulator (2.1) should have a camera. This intent opens the camera app (don't do it on 2.2 emu as the camera app will FC) on the device and and then returns the photos so hte emulator will just return the cartoon android dude.Anyways, which device are you using? And are there any camera apps running (like if it takes a long time to acquire because someone doesn't release the camera in another app things get bad).

Comment: If it works the first time it's probably a release issue. Have you tried releasing the camera inside the startActivityForResult()

Comment: you order the camera to store the taken picture in a specific file, maybe you open the file after capturing an hold it open at the second call?

Comment: Is this on a device or the emulator? Android cameras work differently on different devices. Might want to check on a couple of devices to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to release the camera object - it is even impossible because you do not have a handle to it. This object is released inside the capture activity you are calling.

Are you always using the same file path? If yes try to generate a unique one each time. If this do not help, it looks evidently like a device specific bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

to call default camera activity.

and use next code to retrieve the picture just taken:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

and add permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: it returns in -1 and no intent data in galaxy tab

Comment: In that case use temp file to store your picture    
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri
                    .fromFile(new File(filePath)));

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Then I came up with this solution, and it is working fine for me.

When you call the camera activity, in EXTRA_OUTPUT pass an Uri of a temp file on the storage card. When the camera activity come back, in the onActivityResult() callback method, get that temp file created previously, and add it to the MediaStore. At the end delete the temp file.